# Translation on X operator

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I need to show that given $[x, p_x]=i\hbar$ then the following is true:
$$
e^{iap_x/\hbar}f(x)e^{-iap_x/\hbar}=f(x+a)
$$
for a general function $f(x)$. I've tried using Taylor Series for both exponentials but it only seem to get more complicated and I'm not sure if thats the right approach. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Expand $f(x+a)$ about $x$ and make use of the momentum opertor $ \hat{p_x} =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)

Comment: First review the Taylor expansion in the language of [Lagrange's shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator). Then translate derivatives into the QM formalism. Your question has two dramatically disjoint part: fact, and then language.

Comment: Yes, i am certain. I just managed to solve the problem though, i'll post an answer with the properties i used to prove this relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed yo solve the problem using the following:
First i showed that
$$
e^{iap_x/\hbar}xe^{-iap_x/\hbar}=f(x+a)
$$
To do that i used the following properties: Given that $[x,p_x]=i\hbar$ and $[x[x,p_x]]=0$ then
$$
[f(p_x),x]=f'(p_x)[p_x,x]=-i\hbar f'(x)
$$
So for the exponentials we have
$$
[e^{iap_x/\hbar},x]=-i\hbar\frac{ia}{\hbar} e^{iap_x/\hbar}=e^{iap_x/\hbar}x-xe^{iap_x/\hbar}\\
\Rightarrow e^{iap_x/\hbar}x=(x+a)e^{iap_x/\hbar}
$$
Substituting back in the first equation:
$$
e^{iap_x/\hbar}xe^{-iap_x/\hbar}=(x+a)e^{iap_x/\hbar}e^{-iap_x/\hbar}=(x+a)
$$
Now i can use the propertie $f(e^{-\lambda A}Be^{\lambda A})=e^{-\lambda A}f(B)e^{\lambda A}$ valid since $[x[x,p_x]]=0$. Since $\hat{X} = x$ we have
$$
e^{iap_x/\hbar}f(\hat{X})e^{-iap_x/\hbar}=e^{iap_x/\hbar}f(x)e^{-iap_x/\hbar}\\
=f(e^{iap_x/\hbar}xe^{-iap_x/\hbar}) =f(x+a)
$$